# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53]

Tags: gradle, katalon

I am trying to build the katalon project but constantly getting this error from Gradle.

Command:
gradle katalonCopyDependencies

Error:
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

its working for other team members. I am using MacBook and installed latest java.

can anyone help.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably using Gradle 7.0 or newer but on a project designed for an older version. If there is a wrapper-script (`gradlew`), use that. If not, ask your team members what the project requires.

Comment: Thanks @BjørnVester, I used a older version of Gradle and it worked, thank you so much.